# Is this blended wing body trijet airliner real?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-identification

[image]

Is it a commercial plane? Is this a better design in any way than regular engines on the wings?

Comment: This looks fake.

Comment: It's an Adobe Photoshop Trijet. Was manufactured in Soviet Russia in total secret.

Comment: If it would be real, with that main gear so forward, I would expect it to tailstrike on every landing.

Comment: ahh so much for whats app and the nice people on the int webs.

Comment: Thunderbirds are Go!

Comment: With those flaps it is totally unstable in pitch. The tiny elevons could not compensate, even with a super-responsive FCS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a blended body design. It is a hoax.  See similar photo from Popular Science magazine 2003 on wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blended_wing_body

[image]

By Source (WP:NFCC#4), Fair use, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=37713174

Comment: it's not so much a hoax as a concept under study at the time that led nowhere.

Comment: The photograph depicting it as a commercial airliner is a hoax. The aircraft design, is not a hoax. But the question was regarding a "trijet airliner."

Comment: Boeing released some concept art showing what the concept would look like as an airliners. I'm not sure if the photograph you show is a hoax or one of those images.

Answer (score 7):

Though the aircraft is not real, it is apparently based on the [Boeing X-48B Blended wing body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-48) experimental vehicle.

[image: Boeing X-48B]

[According to NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/news/X-Press/50th_anniversary/on_the_horizon/bwb.html),

> Potential benefits of the aircraft include increased volume for carrying capacity, efficient aerodynamics for reduced fuel burn and possibly significant reductions in noise due to propulsion integration options..

Comment: Also, a lot of middle seats!